# How can i avoid onEndReached triggered 2 times in Reactnative Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am using a library called react-native-swipe-list-view. It seems similar to Flatlist.

With onEndReachedThreshold set to 0.5 and scrolling down, onEndReach is triggered and the hi object is pushed to the list.
However, when the hi object is pushed due to scrolling, onEndReache is triggered again immediately, and the same hi object is pushed, resulting in duplication.

How can I avoid duplicate triggers?

this is my code

```
        import {SwipeListView} from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';

        const EndReached = useCallback(() => {
            list.push(hi);
        }, [hi]);




        <SwipeListView
                data={list}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={() => {
                EndReached();
                }}
            />
```